# Passing hidden value to a php variable in input tag

Tags: php, html, input, get, hidden

I am new to coding and pardon me if it a silly thing I am missing. I have searched through the forum & did not find an answer that suits my need. I have 2 files: jobs.php & jobprocess.php

Jobs.php goes as

```
<?php session_start();
include('dbConnect.php');
$q1="abc";  
$q2="pqr";  
$q3="xyz";  
$opportunity=29;    
echo "Opportunity is". $opportunity;
?>

<html>
<head>
<div align="center">

<form method="post" method="post" action="jobprocess.php">


<input type="text" name="q1" placeholder="<?php echo $q1;?>"><br>
<input type="text" name="q2" placeholder="<?php echo $q2;?>"><br>
<input type="text" name="q3" placeholder="<?php echo $q3;?>"><br>
<input type="hidden" name="opportunity" value="<?php echo $opportunity;?>">


<ul class="actions">
<li><input type="submit" name="submit" value="I would like to join!! "></li>
</ul>                           
</form>                                 
</div>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

jobprocess.php goes with the code

```
<?php session_start();
include('dbConnect.php');


$opportunity = $_GET['opportunity'];
echo "opportunity is " . $opportunity;
?>
```

Unfortunately, the above code is not defining value="29" for opportunity on 2nd page. Thanks in advance

Comment: your html is invalid

Answer (score 2):

If you echo anything before the `html` tag it would effectively make the html invalid. Also, the `head` of the document MUST not have presentational html elements such as `forms`, `divs` etc

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include('dbConnect.php');
    $q1="abc";  
    $q2="pqr";  
    $q3="xyz";  
    $opportunity=29;    

?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>must have a title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            echo "Opportunity is". $opportunity;
        ?>
        <div align="center">
            <form method="post" method="post" action="jobprocess.php">
                <input type="text" name="q1" placeholder="<?php echo $q1;?>"><br>
                <input type="text" name="q2" placeholder="<?php echo $q2;?>"><br>
                <input type="text" name="q3" placeholder="<?php echo $q3;?>"><br>
                <input type="hidden" name="opportunity" value="<?php echo $opportunity;?>">
                <ul class="actions">
                    <li><input type="submit" name="submit" value="I would like to join!! "></li>
                </ul>                           
            </form>                                 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And because the form is set to `POST` you should probably check and use the POSTed variable rather than a GET variable

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include('dbConnect.php');


    $opportunity = $_POST['opportunity'];
    echo "opportunity is " . $opportunity;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly my answer that suggested using session variable instead of hidden form field was deleted?! I guess session variables are illegal now?

The answer was chosen for the best answer even.